# Programmatically make a Google Drive document available offline

Tags: android, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

Within the Google Drive app it is possible for me to manually "pin" certain documents that I want to be available offline.

The function I am talking about is:

Open the drive app > My Drive > Tap & hold on the doc you want > "Make available offline"

Once downloaded it is then available in the offline folder of the Drive app.

If I know the ID of the document is it possible for me to do this "pinning" programmatically?

If so how? If not, why not and when will I be able to?

I'm not necessarily looking for a step by step or hand holding on how to do it (but I won't turn it down), just a nudge or pointer in the right direction, as of yet I've not found any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing with this. On my Android tablet, I marked a PDF file stored on my Google drive as "make available offline". I then made sure it had finished downloading and re-synced with Google Drive on the tablet. Then moving over to my Android phone (hooked up to same Google Account). I performed a sync and checked the offline folder.

The PDF file was not made available offline on the phone even though I had marked it as so on the tablet. Thus it's safe to assume that the "offline" flag/attribute is device specific and is not something that is stored in Google's cloud.

This implies that in order to programatically mark a file as available offline, you'll need to do it from each Android device itself, it's not something you'll be able to do from a web service. I'm not an Android expert but you might look into intents to see if there's any options there.

Comment: Do you know of a published list of intents? I've always found it difficult to work out what intend I need to use as they dont seem to be well documented. On https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui it tells you how to hook into the "open with" menu but thats where the android integration seems to stop.

Comment: No, sorry. As I said, I'm not much of an Android dev.